# How to draw such a layout in android where the black spots are buttons

Tags: android

Hi developers can anyone help me on how to draw such a layout in android studio where the black spots are the buttons the user interacts with. I am a beginner in android programming.I attached the image in the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/45zKt.png

Comment: Lets start with reading Google official tutorials:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html
Later on check topic of onClickLIstners, Layouts(ReleativeLayout), animations and so on...

Comment: Ya Rafal i did but i failed making diagonal,vertical and horizontal lines that connect to the buttons as in that picture. So if u could help me in anyway please do

Comment: Coul you explain your issue further maybe with code/screenshots or a drawing of what you are looking for. also what is the link y;ou are refering too. i dont see it

Comment: I am missing something or I just can't see any picture. Did you go throught all of tutorials in Android Developers ? There is also plenty tutorial online which could be helpful.

Comment: here is the link to the picture http://i.stack.imgur.com/45zKt.png if you cannot see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The black spot will work as button. you can use onclick listener of the view by which you are creating black spot.

Comment: Thanks Kumar for that. But i mainly want how to put those lines that act as connectors

Comment: Simplest solution is you use a similar image of this, the image line connectors should fit to your buttons, and Image should be first layer of view then add buttons on the corners, so that when user click i=button click will work.

Comment: Ohh OK thanks. But whenever i use that due to many screen resolutions the buttons end up losing there positions

Comment: Adding in two comment : 

1)  Use one image and fixed Height and width of your immediate parent of images and buttons .

For Example your image size is 100*100 then put your parent layout {Relative layout} height and width 100*100,  and then set image as background after, add 9 button on "Top_left","parent_top| center_horizontal","top_right","bottom_left","parent_bottom|center_horizontal""bottom_right","center_vertical | parent_left","center_vertical | parent_right", and "parent_center"  of your relative layout.  and set your button background as black cercle.  then all will done.

Comment: 2) second solution is you will need different images for  MDPI,LDPI,HDPI,XHDPI devices and put in related folders, android will choose the images according to devices.